How to control dispense volume of non-Newtonian fluid
1Dispensing System:

Supply pump supply grease from pail pump to Mastic Pressure Regulator
Air Operated Mastic Regulator (diaphragm type) is set to ~400 Psi(fluid)
On/off Pneumatic Dispense valve at the end of a robot that makes a 5.2cm Diameter circle
Valve has interchangeable Needles currently using (1.6mm ID Needle)

Problem:

Need to dispense 1.11-1.63cc of Molykote G-N metal assembly paste
Cycle time <1s

The pail of paste includes mineral oil for delivery through the hose. The pail is mixed before it is used in the equipment.
Currently using a syringe to measure volume
I would like to know is there any way to get the volume within tolerance without investing in a metered dispense system.






You can buy mechanical metering dispensers which are basically power-activated syringes. Or, consider the following:
Grease guns as used by professional mechanics can be rigged with hose feeds that are connected to a barrel of grease, so they can dispense grease all day long from a bulk source.
These guns can also be bought to powered by compressed air so the mechanic can quickly dispense a glob of grease simply by pulling a trigger on the gun handle.
An air-driven grease gun will have an adjustment on it to set the amount of grease delivered per trigger pull. Search for them on professional mechanic tool supplier web pages.
These guns are positive displacement pumps which are inherently unaffected by non-newtonian behavior of the dispensed product.

Use a peristaltic pump - given volume delivered per revolution.
